# Alternate formula for second derivative of single-variable real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I am familiar with the following fact (second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622431/equivalence-between-definitions-of-derivative)): given a function $f: \R \to \R$ that is differentiable at $a \in \R$, it is true that
$$ f'(a) = 2 \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a - h)}{h} .$$
This lead me to explore whether similar looking formula exist for higher derivatives (obviously we can replace $f$ above with $f''$, so more interesting ones). Assuming $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$, we also have
\begin{align*}
f''(a) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a + h) - f'(a)}{h} \\
       &\color{red}{=} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f'(a + 2h) - f'(a + h)}{h} \right) -  \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f'(a + h) - f'(a)}{h} \right)}{h} .\\
\end{align*}
At this point, if we could remove the inside limits, we would get the formula
$$ f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + 2h) - 2f(a + h) + f(a)}{h^2} $$
which I think (?) I have seen before, but two things lead me to doubt this.

1. Can we remove the inside limits?
2. Even if we could, isn't the above mathematics abuse of notation? Really shouldn't we be using a variable different than $h$ for the inside limits? (Note this question is regarding the equality highlighted in red, whereas question #1 is concerning the step directly after it.) Maybe this just means that the statement is false, but I vaguely remember seeing a statement exactly like the one above, hence my hesitancy to reject this method of argument.

Comment: You must remove the $'$ symbols on the RHS; e.g., $$f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+2h) - 2f(a+h) + f(a)}{h^2}.$$

Comment: There should not be prime ' symbols in the final formula though, also the "usual" formula is with a centered term $-2f(a)$. Rather than carrying the lim operator, another approach is to start with Taylor expansion with integral remainder.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the final formula, sorry about that.  @zwim, could you elaborate on the Taylor expansion method? Certainly not all functions have Taylor expansions, but maybe this is why you hinted about the remainder.

Comment: I think you're missing a factor of two in your top formula. Right now, if you plug in the identity function $f(x)=x$, you get a derivative of $2$.

Comment: Oops yeah (fixed).

Comment: May be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298208/using-the-same-limit-for-a-second-derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but here is the follow up on my comment.

Let start with a reminder on how to get the Taylor expansion with integral (FTC and integration by parts):

$\displaystyle f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(t)dt=\Big[(t-x)f'(t)\Big]_{x_0}^x-
\int_{x_0}^x (t-x)f''(t)dt$

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x (x-t)f''(t)dt$$

Applying in $\quad\begin{cases}x=a+2h\\x_0=a+h\end{cases}\quad$ and $\quad\begin{cases}x=a\\x_0=a+h\end{cases}\quad$ we get:

$\displaystyle f(a+2h)=f(a+h)+hf'(a+h)+\int_{a+h}^{a+2h}(a+2h-t)f''(t)dt$

$\displaystyle f(a)=f(a+h)-hf'(a+h)+\int_{a+h}^{a}(a-t)f''(t)dt$

After summation of these two formulas we obtain:

$\displaystyle f(a+2h)-2f(a+h)+f(a)=\int_{a+h}^{a+2h}(a+2h-t)f''(t)dt+\int_{a+h}^{a}(a-t)f''(t)dt$

Notice now that if we replace $f''(t)$ by a constant $K$ in these integrals, then they both evaluate to the same value $\frac 12h^2K$.

In particular:

- for $K=f''(a)$ we get $h^2f''(a)$ on the RHS
- for $K=\epsilon$ we get $h^2\epsilon$ on the RHS

Assuming the local continuity of $f''$ in $a$ we can bound $|f''(t)-f''(a)|<\epsilon$

Therefore subtracting $h^2f''(a)$ on both side, we make $f''(t)-f''(a)$ appear inside the integrals and:

> $\displaystyle \Big|f(a+2h)-2f(a+h)+f(a)-h^2f''(a)\Big|<h^2\epsilon$

Which is the desired result (well we have to divide by $h^2$, select a delta such  that $|t-a|<h$ gives the desired $\epsilon$, but you got the point).

Comment: See also a variant on Schwarz derivative formula https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2480675/399263 using the same technique.